# How to insert an XML element in XmlSerializer?

Tags: android, xml

I am preparing an XML element called artist which has albums as sub elements. The album elements are prepared in a separate function. In the following code snippet albumElements is a String array which contains XML elements of the album. I am not sure how can I insert these ready made XML elements in the artist element. I am using the function text() in the XmlSerializer but it seems to escape the tags in the album elements, what can I do to do it properly? I want an XML that looks like this

```
            <artist name ="someone">
               <album name = "blah1"/>
               <album name = "blah2"/>
            </artist>
```

The code looks like this..

```
        XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();

        try 
        {
            serializer.setOutput(artistElementWriter);              
            serializer.startTag("", "artist");
            serializer.attribute("", "name", artist);

            for (String albumElement : albumElements) 
            {
                serializer.text(albumElement);
            }

            serializer.endTag("", "artist");
            serializer.flush();
        }   
        catch (IOException e) 
        {               
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
```

Any help ?
thanks,

Comment: I suggest you use SQLite to store your data instead of XML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();

    try 
    {
        serializer.setOutput(artistElementWriter);              
        serializer.startTag("", "artist");
        serializer.attribute("", "name", artist);

        for (String albumElement : albumElements) 
        {
             artistElementWriter.write(albumElement);
        }

        serializer.endTag("", "artist");
        serializer.flush();
    }   
    catch (IOException e) 
    {               
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: albumElement is a full element includes tags for album

Comment: aah .. got your question now .... you could use StringWriter class to insert the complete text without escaping.

Comment: yes, I already figured that out, one more thing that needs to be done is to flush the serializer before writing to writer , otherwise tags get in wrong order because we write directly to writer and then serizlizer writes later on flush